# Efficient computation of a loop of integrals in Python

Tags: python, vectorization, numba, probability-density, coding-efficiency

I was wondering how to speed up the following code in where I compute a probability function which involves numerical integrals and then I compute some confidence margins.

Some possibilities that I have thought about are Numba or vectorization of the code

EDIT:
I have made minor modifications because there was a mistake. I am looking for some modifications that provide major time improvements (I know that there are some minor changes that would provide some minor time improvements, such as repeated functions, but I am not concerned about them)
The code is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Jan 26 17:05:46 2021

@author: Ignacio
"""

import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps

def pdf(V,alfa_points):
    alfa=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,alfa_points)
    return simps(1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)/np.sqrt(sigma_R2)*np.exp(-(V*np.cos(alfa)-eR)**2/2/sigma_R2)*1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)/np.sqrt(sigma_I2)*np.exp(-(V*np.sin(alfa)-eI)**2/2/sigma_I2),alfa)
    
def find_nearest(array,value):
    array=np.asarray(array)
    idx = (np.abs(array-value)).argmin()
    return array[idx]

N = 20
n=np.linspace(0,N-1,N)
d=1
sigma_An=0.1
sigma_Pn=0.2

An=np.ones(N)
Pn=np.zeros(N)

Vs=np.linspace(0,30,1000)
inc=np.max(Vs)/len(Vs)
th=np.linspace(0,np.pi/2,250)
R=np.sum(An*np.cos(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[:,np.newaxis])*n*d),axis=1)
I=np.sum(An*np.sin(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[:,np.newaxis])*n*d),axis=1)

fmin=np.zeros(len(th))
fmax=np.zeros(len(th))
for tt in range(len(th)):
    eR=np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2/2)*np.sum(An*np.cos(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[tt])*n*d))
    eI=np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2/2)*np.sum(An*np.sin(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[tt])*n*d)) 
    
    sigma_R2=1/2*np.sum(An*sigma_An**2)+1/2*(1-np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2))*np.sum(An**2)+1/2*np.sum(np.cos(2*(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[tt])*n*d))*((An**2+sigma_An**2)*np.exp(-2*sigma_Pn**2)-An**2*np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2)))
    sigma_I2=1/2*np.sum(An*sigma_An**2)+1/2*(1-np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2))*np.sum(An**2)-1/2*np.sum(np.cos(2*(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[tt])*n*d))*((An**2+sigma_An**2)*np.exp(-2*sigma_Pn**2)-An**2*np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2))) 
    
    PDF=np.zeros(len(Vs))
    for vv in range(len(Vs)):
        PDF[vv]=pdf(Vs[vv],100)
    total=simps(PDF,Vs)
    values=np.cumsum(PDF)*inc/total
    xval_05=find_nearest(values,0.05)
    fmin[tt]=Vs[values==xval_05]
    xval_95=find_nearest(values,0.95)
    fmax[tt]=Vs[values==xval_95]
```

Comment: A quick look: why run `find_nearest` twice over your array: change it to run once and return both values. Your eR and eI share significant overlap of the formulas: factor out the common elements so you dont have to recalculate. Same with the pdf function: the return statement has several double calculated values.

Comment: I tired to run the code but failed. A general suggestion: take the double-for loop into a function and decorate it with `numba.njit`, and unzip code out of `pdf` and `find_nearest` functions. (Function calls are expensive in Python so you gain the performance by writing long, ugly, non-pythonic function with numba.njit)

Answer (score 1):

**This version's speedup: 31x**

A simple profiling (`%%prun`) reveals that most of the time is spent in `simps`.

You are in control of the integration done in `pdf()`: for example, you can use the trapeze method instead of Simpson with negligible numerical difference if you increase a bit the resolution of `alpha`. In fact, the higher resolution obtained by a higher sampling of `alpha` more than makes up for the difference between `simps` and `trapeze` (see picture at the bottom as for why). This is by far the highest speedup. We go one bit further by implementing the trapeze method ourselves instead of using `scipy`, since it is so simple. This alone yields marginal gain, but opens the door for a more drastic optimization (below, about `pdf2D`.

Also, the remaining `simps(PDF, ...)` goes faster when it knows that the `dx` step is constant, so we can just say so instead of passing the whole `alpha` array.

You can avoid doing the loop to compute `PDF` and use `np.vectorize(pdf)` directly on `Vs`, or better (as in the code below), do a 2-D version of that calculation.

There are some other minor things (such as using an index directly `fmin[tt] = Vs[closest(values, 0.05)]` instead of finding the index, returning the value, and then using a boolean mask for where `values == xval_05`), or taking all the constants (including `alpha`) outside functions and avoid recalculating every time.

This above gives us a 5.2x improvement. There is a number of things I don't understand in your code, e.g. why having `An` (ones) and `Pn` (zeros)?

But, importantly, another ~6x speedup comes from the observation that, since we are implementing our own `trapeze` method by using `numpy` primitives, we can actually do it in 2D in one go for the whole `PDF`.

The final speed up of the code below is 31x.  I believe that a better understanding of "the big picture" of what you want to do would yield additional, perhaps substantial, speed gains.

Modified code:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import simps


alpha_points = 200  # more points as we'll use trapeze not simps
alpha = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, alpha_points)
cosalpha = np.cos(alpha)
sinalpha = np.sin(alpha)
d_alpha = np.mean(np.diff(alpha))  # constant dx
coeff = 1 / np.sqrt(2*np.pi)
Vs=np.linspace(0,30,1000)
d_Vs = np.mean(np.diff(Vs))  # constant dx
inc=np.max(Vs)/len(Vs)

def f2D(Vs, eR, sigma_R2, eI, sigma_I2):
    a = coeff / np.sqrt(sigma_R2)
    b = coeff / np.sqrt(sigma_I2)
    y = a * np.exp(-(np.outer(cosalpha, Vs) - eR)**2 / 2 / sigma_R2) * b * np.exp(-(np.outer(sinalpha, Vs) - eI)**2 / 2 / sigma_I2)
    return y

def pdf2D(Vs, eR, sigma_R2, eI, sigma_I2):
    y = f2D(Vs, eR, sigma_R2, eI, sigma_I2)
    s = y.sum(axis=0) - (y[0] + y[-1]) / 2  # our own impl of trapeze, on 2D y
    return s * d_alpha

def closest(a, val):
    return np.abs(a - val).argmin()

N = 20
n = np.linspace(0,N-1,N)
d = 1
sigma_An = 0.1
sigma_Pn = 0.2

An=np.ones(N)
Pn=np.zeros(N)

th = np.linspace(0,np.pi/2,250)
R = np.sum(An*np.cos(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[:,np.newaxis])*n*d),axis=1)
I = np.sum(An*np.sin(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[:,np.newaxis])*n*d),axis=1)

fmin=np.zeros(len(th))
fmax=np.zeros(len(th))
for tt in range(len(th)):
    eR=np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2/2)*np.sum(An*np.cos(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[tt])*n*d))
    eI=np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2/2)*np.sum(An*np.sin(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[tt])*n*d)) 
    
    sigma_R2=1/2*np.sum(An*sigma_An**2)+1/2*(1-np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2))*np.sum(An**2)+1/2*np.sum(np.cos(2*(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[tt])*n*d))*((An**2+sigma_An**2)*np.exp(-2*sigma_Pn**2)-An**2*np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2)))
    sigma_I2=1/2*np.sum(An*sigma_An**2)+1/2*(1-np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2))*np.sum(An**2)-1/2*np.sum(np.cos(2*(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[tt])*n*d))*((An**2+sigma_An**2)*np.exp(-2*sigma_Pn**2)-An**2*np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2))) 
    
    PDF=pdf2D(Vs, eR, sigma_R2, eI, sigma_I2)
    total = simps(PDF, dx=d_Vs)
    values = np.cumsum(PDF) * inc / total
    fmin[tt] = Vs[closest(values, 0.05)]
    fmax[tt] = Vs[closest(values, 0.95)]
```

Note: most of the `fmin` and `fmax` are `np.allclose()` compared with the original function, but some of them have a small error: after some digging, it turns out that the implementation here is more precise as that function `f()` can be pretty abrupt, and more `alpha` points actually help (and more than compensate the minuscule lack of precision due to using trapeze instead of Simpson).

For example, at index `tt=244, vv=400`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Really interesting. I have managed to do it with Numba with good time improvement (with some necessary changes such as removing the functions or the  simps function as well). I will compare (or even combine) with your solution to  enhance performances and I will summarize the results here.

Comment: sounds good. The version I have here takes 1.1s for the full calculation, using a higher resolution on `alpha` (more precise result, even though we use a trapeze approximation instead of Simpson).

Answer (score 0):

Considering several methods, the one that provides the largest time improvement is the Numba method. The method proposed by Pierre is very interesting and it does not require to install other packages, which is an asset.

However, in the examples that I have computed, the time improvement is not as large as with the numba example, specially when the points in th grows to a few tenths of thousands (which is my actual case). I post here the Numba code just in case someone is interested:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def margins(val_min,val_max):
    fmin=np.zeros(len(th))
    fmax=np.zeros(len(th))
    for tt in range(len(th)):    
        eR=np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2/2)*np.sum(An*np.cos(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[tt])*n*d))
        eI=np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2/2)*np.sum(An*np.sin(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[tt])*n*d))
    
        sigma_R2=1/2*np.sum(An*sigma_An**2)+1/2*(1-np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2))*np.sum(An**2)+1/2*np.sum(np.cos(2*(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[tt])*n*d))*((An**2+sigma_An**2)*np.exp(-2*sigma_Pn**2)-An**2*np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2)))
        sigma_I2=1/2*np.sum(An*sigma_An**2)+1/2*(1-np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2))*np.sum(An**2)-1/2*np.sum(np.cos(2*(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[tt])*n*d))*((An**2+sigma_An**2)*np.exp(-2*sigma_Pn**2)-An**2*np.exp(-sigma_Pn**2)))
    
        Vs=np.linspace(0,30,1000)
        inc=np.max(Vs)/len(Vs)
        integration_points=200
        PDF=np.zeros(len(Vs))
        for vv in range(len(Vs)):
            PDF[vv]=np.trapz(1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)/np.sqrt(sigma_R2)*np.exp(-(Vs[vv]*np.cos(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,integration_points))-eR)**2/2/sigma_R2)*1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)/np.sqrt(sigma_I2)*np.exp(-(Vs[vv]*np.sin(np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,integration_points))-eI)**2/2/sigma_I2),np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,integration_points))
              
        total=np.trapz(PDF,Vs)
        values=np.cumsum(PDF)*inc/total
        idx = (np.abs(values-val_min)).argmin()
        xval_05=values[idx]            
        fmin[tt]=Vs[np.where(values==xval_05)[0][0]]
        idx = (np.abs(values-val_max)).argmin()   
        xval_95=values[idx]
        fmax[tt]=Vs[np.where(values==xval_95)[0][0]]

    return fmin,fmax


N = 20
n=np.linspace(0,N-1,N)
d=1
sigma_An=1/2**6
sigma_Pn=2*np.pi/2**6
An=np.ones(N)
Pn=np.zeros(N)

th=np.linspace(0,np.pi/2,250)

R=np.sum(An*np.cos(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[:,np.newaxis])*n*d),axis=1)
I=np.sum(An*np.sin(Pn+2*np.pi*np.sin(th[:,np.newaxis])*n*d),axis=1)

F=R+1j*I
Fa=np.abs(F)/np.max(np.abs(F))

fmin, fmax = margins(0.05,0.95)
```